# Ruby String interpolation throws syntax error in 1.9.3 but not 2.3.1

Tags: ruby, string-interpolation

Sorry in advance for the large chunk of code. I'm concerned that I may have missed something that is obvious in context.

```
  def remove_runbook_items(runbook_id, runbook_item_id)
    item_id = runbook_item_id.to_s
    method = 'POST'
    url = @the_endpoint
    data = {
        invokeDetail: {
            process: 'remove_runbook_items',
            parameters: {
                runbook_id: runbook_id,
                runbook_items: {
                    "#{item_id}": {
                        cores: options[:cores],
                        ram: options[:ram],
                        rank: options[:rank],
                        wait_time: options[:wait_time]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    data.merge! @common_data
    result = send_request(method, url, data.to_json)
    result['resultDetail'] # Returns contents of response from REST API server
  end
```

The offending line is the one that says **"#{item_id}": {**

The block of text called "data" is converted into a json, so I *must* interpolate the string "item_id" or else it will literally spit out "item_id" in the resulting request, rather than item_id's contents. Actually, if there's a way to get at the contents without interpolation, I'd love to know it.

So when I interpolate my string in this way, it works just fine on Ruby 2.3.1. However, when I try to run the same code on a machine using Ruby 1.9.3, I get a litany of syntax errors anywhere I have interpolated a string like this:

```
/home/mydir/mydir/mydir/mydir/mydir/restapi_helper.rb:1122: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting tASSOC
                    "#{device_id}": {
                                   ^
/home/mydir/mydir/mydir/mydir/mydir/restapi_helper.rb:1128: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end
/home/mydir/mydir/mydir/mydir/mydir/restapi_helper.rb:1163: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting tASSOC
                    "#{item_id}": {
                                 ^
/home/mydir/mydir/mydir/mydir/mydir/restapi_helper.rb:1169: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end
/home/mydir/mydir/mydir/mydir/mydir/restapi_helper.rb:1257: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting tASSOC
                    "#{item_id}": {
                                 ^
/home/mydir/mydir/mydir/mydir/mydir/restapi_helper.rb:1263: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
```

Does anybody have any advice? Upgrading the version of ruby on the test machines is unfortunately not an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not iterpolation that is the problem.

`{ symbol: value }` is a new syntax, which is a shortcut for `{ :symbol => value }`. In its first iteration, I don't think it supported `{ "symbol": value }` automatic string symbolification feature. Use the old-fashioned `{ "symbol".to_sym => value }` if backward compatibility is a goal.

(If you *know* that all you're doing is converting to JSON, you can even just leave it as `{ "string" => value }`, comforted by the knowledge that JSON does not make a distinction between strings and symbols; but I'd consider it a code smell.)

Comment: `{ :"symbol": value }` should work in 1.9 as well (note leading colon within string.)

Comment: @mudasobwa Do you mean `{ :"symbol" => value }`?

Comment: @Jordan Oh, yes, indeed `{ :"symbol" => value }`, sorry for messing things up.

Comment: You save my day! Thanks!